# embeded virtual keyboard in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I have wrote an angular code for showing a virtual keyboard using **[angular-virtual-keyboard](http://the-darc.github.io/angular-virtual-keyboard/)**, The code is working fine and the virtual keyboard is coming fine when we click the text-field. The issue is that I want the virtual keyboard to be shown as directly in the page and not by any click.

How we can achieve this.

Can anyone please  help me on this, do we have any other component in angularjs which supports virtual keyboard

My code is as given below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bujvs55h/)**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    Click this textfield to see the Virtual Keyboard<br/><input type='text' ng-model="yourModel" ng-virtual-keyboard/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated the fiddle with the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/bujvs55h/1/

Just add this directive:

```
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the thing is that I want the virtual keyboard to be displayed in the webpage as always not that it should come when we click the textfield

Comment: It comes out when you load the page, you haven't to click anything.

Comment: but its going off when I click some where

Comment: oh well, if you want to be sticked you should ask the module's author

Comment: ooh...do we have any component like that in angularjs